# CodePush ReactNative "auto roll-back" iOS app version after reopen app

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

on iOS, After modifying some features and stuff in our app we just released both new versions over the air and all goes ok. The app discovers the update accordingly, then installs it and so restarts the app.

Everything was ok until I realize that when I restart the app it kind of roll-back to the default store version (w/o our new updates).

But on android, it is working fine.

I am using:

```
"react-native": "0.66.4",
"react-native-code-push": "^7.1.0",
```

React Native Code:

```
CodePush.sync(
{
  installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
  mandatoryInstallMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
  updateDialog: true,
},
```

Xcode Code:

```
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>

...

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
 // return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
  return [CodePush bundleURL];
#endif
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: same issue here it was working fine till this last update i guess something wrong with ios, also there is no increment of number Rollback inside appcenter website

Comment: try this one, it works for me

xcode > select project -> build settings -> search "Preprocessor Macros" > change value for release "DEBUG=0" and debug "DEBUG=1". 

after that re-run the build